# Wordpress loop only showing one record in query post

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress Site or its Blog section I did a WP_Query post.

The loop is within a custom template its showing only one record while I have few post entries.

I think I have done correctly...

Please do let me why it is not looping the records.

```
<?php    get_header();
?>

<div id="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span9">
        <?php 
                        $arr = array(
                            'post_type'         => 'post',
                            'posts_per_page'    => 10,
                            'orderby'           => 'date',
                            'order'             => 'DESC',
                            'post_status'       => 'publish'
                        );

                        $query = new WP_Query($arr);

                        if(count($query->posts) > 0):

                            $i = 0;

                    ?>
        <?php  while($query->have_posts()): $i++;?>
        <?php $query->the_post();

            if(has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())){

                $url_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'thumb_700x260', array('alt' => trim(get_the_title())));
                $url_thumbnail_news = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'thumb_700x260', array('alt' => trim(get_the_title())));

            } else {

                $url_thumbnail = '<image src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/no-thumbnail.jpg" title="No Thumbnail" alt="Free Nile Theme - Wordpress Theme from ThemeLead" />';
                $url_thumbnail_news = '<image src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/no-thumbnail-news.jpg" title="No Thumbnail" alt="Free Nile Theme - Wordpress Theme from ThemeLead" />';

           }

        ?>
        <?php if($i==1):?>
        <div class="drop-shadow lifted"> <a class="nile-thumnail" href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID())?>" title="<?php the_title()?>"><?php echo $url_thumbnail;?></a> </div>
        <div class="the_post">
          <h2 class="bj-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID())?>" title="<?php the_title()?>">
            <?php the_title();?>
            </a></h2>
          <div class="bj-date">
            <?php the_date();?>
            <?php the_time();?>
          </div>
          <div class="bj-des">
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
          </div>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title()?>" class="read-more">
          <?php _e('Read more', APP_TD);?>
          </a> </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php // Reset Query
wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <div class="navigation">
          <div class="alignleft">
            <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?>
          </div>
          <div class="alignright">
            <?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span3"> <?php echo get_default_sidebar();?> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the 'if($i==1)' and corresponding 'endif;' line